# Error en biasCorrection() y downscaleCV() (climate4R)

Tags: r

Tengo el mismo problema para las funciones `biasCorrection()` y `downscaleCV()`. Tiene que ver con el formato de fechas de las estaciones de monitoreo, que cargue de la siguiente manera:

```
nombre.carpeta <- 'datos_transformados_a_ASCII'
meses <- 1:12
anhos <- 2010:2011

y <- loadStationData(dataset = nombre.carpeta, 
                     var="precip", 
                     years = anhos,
                     season = meses,
                     tz='GMT')

[2020-09-30 13:57:10] Loading data ...
[2020-09-30 13:57:10] Retrieving metadata ...
[2020-09-30 13:57:10] Done.
Warning message:
In if (class(out$Data) == "numeric") datadimnames <- "time" :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
```

Donde, si no uso `tz="GMT"`, algunas fechas quedan en NA y el problema se vuelve mayor.

```
y <- loadStationData(dataset = nombre.carpeta, 
                     var="precip", 
                     years = anhos,
                     season = meses

pad applied on the interval: day
Error in seq.Date(xlim[1], xlim[2], (xlim[2] - xlim[1])/10) : 'by' is NA
Además: Warning message:
There are NA values in the column Dates. The records with NA values are returned
in the final rows of the dataframe.
```

Aquí va una muestra:

```
> y$Dates$start[271:286]
 [1] "2010-09-28 00:00:00" "2010-09-29 00:00:00" "2010-09-30 00:00:00" "2010-10-01 00:00:00" "2010-10-02 00:00:00"
 [6] "2010-10-03 00:00:00" "2010-10-04 00:00:00" "2010-10-05 00:00:00" "2010-10-06 00:00:00" "2010-10-07 00:00:00"
[11] "2010-10-08 00:00:00" "2010-10-09 00:00:00" NA                    "2010-10-11 00:00:00" "2010-10-12 00:00:00"
[16] "2010-10-13 00:00:00"
```

En fin, cuando ejecuto la función `biasCorrection()`, me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
pr.sum.bias.correction <- biasCorrection(x=pr.sum,
                                   y = y,
                                   precipitation = TRUE,
                                   #window = 10,
                                   method = "pqm")# %>% redim(drop = TRUE)

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

y con `downscaleCV()`, lo siguiente:

```
M6cv.bin <- downscaleCV(x = x, y = y_bin,
                        method = "GLM",
                        family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                        folds = folds,
                        prepareData.args = list(global.vars = NULL,
                                                local.predictors = NULL,
                                                spatial.predictors = spatial.pars.M6,
                                                combined.only = TRUE))

fold: 1 --> calculating...
[2020-09-30 14:05:31] Performing PC analysis on 3 variables plus a combination ...
[2020-09-30 14:05:31] Done.
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(field.list[[1]]$Dates$start) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?
Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a este problema fue ocupar como referencia el formato del mes de enero (o cualquier otro mes de 31 días). He trabajado más con la función `biasCorrection()`, pero espero que también sea aplicable a `downscaleCV()`. Para esto elabore la función `nuevas_fechas()`, y lo aplique para los datos de las estaciones metereologicas y grillas de ERA5, desde febrero a diciembre (hice un loop, donde 'i' representaba al numero del mes, por eso esta 'iteracion' en la función):

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

nuevas_fechas <- function(lista.climate4R, entregar_fecha_inicio=TRUE, iteracion, tz=NULL){
  
  # lista.climate4R <- pr.sum.original
  # iteracion <- i
  
  fecha_inicio <- lista.climate4R$Dates$start
  fecha_fin <- lista.climate4R$Dates$end
  
  if(iteracion<=9){mes.i <- paste0('-', 0, iteracion,'-')} else(mes.i <- paste0('-', iteracion,'-'))
  
  nueva_fecha_inicio <- gsub(mes.i, '-01-', fecha_inicio)
  id <- str_detect(nueva_fecha_inicio, '01-31')
  
  if(iteracion==2){nuevos_anhos <- year(nueva_fecha_inicio[id])-1} else(nuevos_anhos <- year(nueva_fecha_inicio[id]))
  
  
  if(is.null(tz)){nueva_fecha_inicio[id] <- paste0(nuevos_anhos, '-12-31 00:00:00')
  } else(nueva_fecha_inicio[id] <- paste0(nuevos_anhos, '-12-31', ' ', tz)) 
  
  nueva_fecha_fin_preliminar <- gsub(mes.i, '-01-', fecha_fin)
  
  mes.siguiente.i <- iteracion+1
  if(mes.siguiente.i<=8){mes.j <- paste0('-', 0, (iteracion+1),'-')} else(mes.j <- paste0('-', (iteracion+1),'-'))
  
  nueva_fecha_fin <- gsub(mes.j, '-02-', nueva_fecha_fin_preliminar)
  
  fecha_inicio_output <- list(start=fecha_inicio, start=nueva_fecha_inicio)
  fecha_fin_output <- list(end=fecha_fin, end=nueva_fecha_fin)
  
  if(entregar_fecha_inicio){return(fecha_inicio_output)} else(return(fecha_fin_output))
  
}
```

Luego de ejecutar la función `biasCorrection()` de forma exitosa, transforme las fechas a sus valores originales, de nuevo, con la función `nuevas_fechas()`.

Como enero tiene 31 días y el resto de meses varía en este sentido, `biasCorrection()` genera NA's debido a que no tiene información para la corrección. Por ende, elabore otra función que descarta estos valores y le entrega el formato requerido para volver a incorporarlo a la lista que genera `biasCorrection()`, este es:

```
formato_datos_para_climate4R <- function(lista.climate4R){

  # lista.climate4R <- pr.sum.corregido.eqm
  
  datos <- lista.climate4R$Data
  
  id.valores.NA <- which(is.na(datos))
  
  if(length(id.valores.NA)==0){datos_depurados <- datos
    } else(c(datos_depurados <- datos[-id.valores.NA],
             attr(datos_depurados, "dimensions") <- "time"))
  
  return(datos_depurados)
  
  }
```

Como observaciones:

- Utilice datos externos a los que ofrece el framework climate4R.
- `biasCorrection()` me genero errores de formato con meses que diferían de los 31 días.
- Las correcciones las aplique de mes a mes, por lo que hice un loop para generar una corrección anual.